# Disappearing of page elements on clicking a button

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I'm having a problem of disappearing of all the elements and stuff on the page.

I'm using C# and ASP.net

When I click on the button, all things, and elements that have been added dynamically in the page, disappear, and go invisible.

Which part makes things go wrong and how to get that problem fixed?

This what have been done so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

public partial class Questions : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public List<string> Ques = new List<string>();
    public List<string> Ans = new List<string>();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            Ques.Clear();
            Ans.Clear();
            get_questions();

            for (int i = 0; i < Ques.Count() && Ans[i] != "null"; i++)
            {
                Draw_answered_questions(Ques[i], Ans[i]);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < Ques.Count(); i++)
            {
                if (Ans[i] == "null")
                    Draw_unanswered_questions(Ques[i]);
            }

            answered.Attributes.Add("class", "displayblock");
            unAnswered.Attributes.Add("class", "displaynone");
            answerArea.Attributes.Add("class", "displaynone");
        }
    }

    //to show questions that have answer.
    protected void Button2_Answered_Questions_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        answered.Attributes.Add("class", "displayblock");
        unAnswered.Attributes.Add("class", "displaynone");
        answerArea.Attributes.Add("class", "displaynone");

        answered.InnerHtml = "";
        Ques.Clear();
        Ans.Clear();
        get_questions();

        for (int i = 0; i < Ques.Count() && Ans[i] != "null"; i++)
        {
            Draw_answered_questions(Ques[i], Ans[i]);
        }
    }

    //to show questions that haven't answer yet.
    protected void Button3_Questions_without_answer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {       unAnswered.Attributes.Add("class", "displayblock");
            answered.Attributes.Add("class", "displaynone");
            answerArea.Attributes.Add("class", "displaynone");

            unAnswered.InnerHtml = "";
            Ques.Clear();
            Ans.Clear();
            get_questions();

            for (int i = 0; i < Ques.Count(); i++)
            {
                if (Ans[i] == "null")
                    Draw_unanswered_questions(Ques[i]);
            }

    }

    //add new question.
    protected void Button1_Ask_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        New_Question(ques_textBox.Text, "null" , 2);
        Draw_unanswered_questions(ques_textBox.Text);

    }

    //get data from database.
    protected void get_questions()
    {
        using (ScrummanagementEntities db = new ScrummanagementEntities())
        {
            var query = from q in db.Questions select q;
            List<Question> copies = query.ToList();
            Ques.Clear();
            Ans.Clear();

            for(int i=0 ; i<copies.Count() ; i++)
            {
                Ques.Add(copies[i].Question1);
                Ans.Add(copies[i].Answer);
            }
        }
    }

    //draw new divs to all answered questions
    protected void Draw_answered_questions(string q , string a)
    {
        HtmlGenericControl newdiv1 = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
        newdiv1.Attributes.Add("class", "question");
        newdiv1.InnerHtml = q;
        answered.Controls.Add(newdiv1);

        HtmlGenericControl newdiv2 = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
        newdiv2.Attributes.Add("class", "answer");
        newdiv2.InnerHtml = a;
        answered.Controls.Add(newdiv2);
    }

    //draw new divs to all unanswered questions
    protected void Draw_unanswered_questions(string q)
    {
        //HtmlGenericControl newdiv1 = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
        //newdiv1.Attributes.Add("class", "unans");
        //newdiv1.Attributes.Add("id", q);
        //newdiv1.InnerHtml = q;
        //newdiv1.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "unans_Click");
        //unAnswered.Controls.Add(newdiv1);

        int index = 0;
        Button b = new Button();
        b.Attributes.Add("class", "unans");
        index++;
        b.Text = q;
        b.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
        unAnswered.Controls.Add(b);
        b.Click += new EventHandler(unans_Click); //problem here

        //b.Attributes.Add("id", q+index.ToString());
        //b.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "unans_Click");
        //b.Attributes.Add("onClick", "unans_Click");
    }

    private void unans_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HtmlGenericControl b = sender as HtmlGenericControl;
        b.InnerHtml = "fffff";

        //HtmlGenericControl newdiv1 = sender as HtmlGenericControl;
        //answerArea.Attributes.Add("class", "displayblock");
        //answered.Attributes.Add("class", "displaynone");
        //unAnswered.Attributes.Add("class", "displaynone");
    }

    //get all data from database
    public void New_Question(string ques, string ans, int proid)
    {
        using (ScrummanagementEntities db = new ScrummanagementEntities())
        {
            Question q = new Question();
            q.Question1 = ques;
            q.Answer = ans;

            db.Questions.Add(q);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
    protected void Button_the_Answer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button b = sender as Button;
        b.Text = "fffff";
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show us the html. Also which button are you clicking?

Comment: When you add controls programmatically to a page in WebForms, you _must_ add them on every postback. WebForms is stateless. What's happening is you're clicking the button, the page is reloading and none of the controls are being rebuilt and added, as your page construction logic is all blocked on PostBack.